# Yii framework 2.0 add CDATA to Response::FORMAT_XML

Tags: php, xml, response, yii2, cdata

I have a page that responses data in XML format. I used this code snippet from Yii 2.0 documentation.

```
$response = Yii::$app->response;
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_XML;    
$response->data = ['a' => 'AX', 'b' => 'BZ', 'c' => 100];
```

The result from the above code is.

```
<response>
   <a>AX</a>
   <b>BZ</b>
   <c>100</c>
</response>
```

Is there anyway to insert this `<![CDATA[ ]]>` into the xml tag which contains string or any character as value. What I want to get is.

```
<response>
   <a>
       <![CDATA[ AX ]]>
   </a>
   <b>
       <![CDATA[ BZ ]]>
   </b>
   <c>100</c>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Yii's source code and docs it is not possible. When using [XmlResponseFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-xmlresponseformatter.html) to transform your data into XML it will only use DOMText classes as children.